# Python: AttributeError: type object 'Ui_Form' has no attribute 'comboBox'

Tags: python

I have two modules test.py and fill_combobox.py. The fill_combobox is for a default values in the combobox. There is still a problem with communication between modules.

test.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import fill_combobox

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 120, 51, 25))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        fill_combobox.fill()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

fill_combobox.py

```
def fill():
    import test
    for i in range(40):
        test.Ui_Form.comboBox.addItems(str(i))
```

Comment: Please specify what is the exact problem you are facing. You will garner more help that way :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your code the line:

```
test.Ui_Form.comboBox.addItems(str(i))
```

Is accessing the *class* `Ui_Form`, not an `Ui_Form` *instance*. As such the class does *not* have any `comboBox` attribute. If you want to use the `Ui_Form` class use the pattern shown at the end of `test.py`:

```
form = QtGui.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(form)
form.show()
```

You should put that code *before* the `for` loop, and in the loop access the `form` instance.

---

If you are doing this in many places it might be better to write your custom widget as:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, ...):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Then you can avoid creating the `Ui_Form` instance and just do:

```
form = MyWidget()
form.show()
```